# Issue after resizing partition for Fedora under VMware Fusion

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora, vmware-fusion

I am running FC9 under VMware Fusion 3.0. I wanted to resize my `/dev/sda2` partition.

In order to do that I did the following:

1. Changed the size of the vmware file (under VMware settings)
2. Rebooted the host to rescue mode without mounted disks
3. `fdisk` - removed and added `/dev/sda2`

   - I had a bigger `/dev/sda2`
4. `lvm pvresize /dev/sda2`
5. `lvm pvdisplay`

   - It showed me a bigger size on `/dev/VolGroup00` for `/dev/sda2`
6. `lvm vgchange -a y`

   - **device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument**
   - **2 logical volume(s) in volume group "VolGroup00" now active**

This is **not true** because there is no `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00` - my whole "/" disappeared.

dmsetup table, shows:

```
VolGroup00-LogVol01: 0 2097152 linear 8:2 38338944  
VolGroup00-LogVol00:
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In step 5 you're running 'lvm vgchange -a y'; shouldn't it be 'lvm vgchange -ay'?  (i.e. no space between a and y)

Here's hoping it's that simple...
-pbr

Comment: I tried both and the result is the same. thx.

Comment: anyway the option is okey while it enabled the LogVol01 logical Volume.